# Какой гем лучше подключить для электронной коммерция в Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ecommerce

Мне нужен гем, который построит каркас магазина(Добавление товара на сайт, в корзину, оплата товара). Я нашел вот это [e-commerce](https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce), но я не знаю как его использовать, как гем не подключишь, но и на его основе проект строить не хочу, так как мой часть проекта уже сделана не касающаяся магазина. Подскажите пожалуйста какие гемы для этого есть? или как правильно подключить  e-commerce? может быть я что то не понимаю..